# Aggregating over map keys using mongo aggregation framework

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a use case where I have documents stored in a mongo collection with one of the columns as map. For example :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("axa"), "date" : "2015-08-05", "key1" : "abc",  "aggregates" : { "x" : 12, "y" : 1 } }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("axa1"), "date" : "2015-08-04", "key1" : "abc",  "aggregates" : { "x" : 4, "y" : 19 } }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("axa2"), "date" : "2015-08-03", "key1" : "abc",  "aggregates" : { "x" : 3, "y" : 13 } }
```

One thing to note is keys inside aggregates sub document could change. for example instead of x and y , it could be z and k or any combination and any number

Now I am pulling that data over from an API and need to use mongo aggregation framework to aggregate over date range. For instance, for the above example, I want to run query for date 08/03 -08/05 and aggregate x and y (group by x and y ) and  the result should be

```
 {  "key1" : "abc",  "aggregates" : { "x" : 19, "y" : 33 } }
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

First you should update you document because `date` is string. You can do that using the [`Bulk()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/bulk.html?highlight=bulk#module-pymongo.bulk) API

```
from datetime import datetime

import pymongo

conn = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = conn.test
col = db.collection

bulk = col.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()
count = 0

for doc in col.find():
    conv_date = datetime.strptime(doc['date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
    bulk.find({'_id': doc['_id']}).update_one({'$set': {'date': conv_date}})
    count = count + 1
    if count % 500 == 0:
        # Execute per 500 operations and re-init.
        bulk.execute()
        bulk = col.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()

# Clean up queues
if count % 500 != 0:
    bulk.execute()
```

---

Then comes the aggregation part:

You need to filter you documents by `date` using the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator. Next [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) your documents by a specified identifier`key1` and apply the accumulator [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum). With [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) you can reshape your document.

```
x = 'x'
y = 'y'

col.aggregate([
    {'$match': { 'date': { '$lte': datetime(2015, 8, 5), '$gte': datetime(2015, 8, 3)}}}, 
    {'$group': {'_id': '$key1', 'x': {'$sum': '$aggregates. ' +x}, 'y': {'$sum': '$aggregates.' + y}}},
    {'$project': {'key1': '$_id', 'aggregates': {'x': '$x', 'y': '$y'}, '_id': 0}} 
])
```

Comment: There is one problem here. I wouldn't know what all keys will be there in aggregates. for example : current example has x and y but there could be z,k,l,m. We would only know that in run time

Comment: I have updated the question. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @user2942227 In this case concatenate expression in `$sum` see my edit

Comment: you are still specifically using x and y right? how will it handle if i have "aggregates" : { "x" : 12, "y" : 1, "z":12, , "k" : 15 }  and now I want sum for x,y,z and k

Comment: @user2942227 just add `z` and `k` to the  **group**  stage just like I did for `x` and `y`